# simple graph modelling / drawing software for efficient everyday use

Tags: graph, drawing, diagram, modeling

I'm looking for a free graph drawing software.

Its main purpose would be to quickly create a map of modules/classes with dependencies, call stacks, all the stuff with some comments. My main requirements are

- simplicity (I don't need a lot of graphical options, like thickness of fading node edges),
- usability & efficiency (I want to create graphs I need in a matter of seconds and using keyboard should be enough in most use cases).

I am aware of the fact that there are numerous such tools but I guess not many of them (if any) meet my requirements.

In short, I need:

- something simple like yEd but where keyboard can be used to quickly add nodes, edges, their content and notes without spending hours on formatting your graph.
- something usable like MindMap but where structure can be fully controlled, directed & undirected edges added.

Answer (score 1):

[GraphVis (e.g., dot)](http://www.graphviz.org/) is really pretty decent, and has an easy export format.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled across http://diagram.ly, pretty good for quickly sketching graphs or diagrams.

Comment: It redirects currently to https://www.draw.io/ it was pretty nice. Did everything that I needed.